# How to enclose an array in a conditional if?

Tags: arrays, conditional-statements

For example, I have the following code:

```
<?php 

$options = array( 

    array(
        "type" => "section",
        "icon" => "acera-icon-preference",
        "title" => "General Settings",
        "id" => "general",
        "expanded" => "true"
    ),
array(
        "under_section" => "ajax_login",
        "type" => "checkbox",
        "name" => "Who's Online Options",
        "id" => array("tigu_whosonline_list", "tigu_whosonline_avatar"),
        "display_checkbox_id" => "tigu_show_whosonline",
        "img_desc" => "", 
        "options" => array("Who's Online List", "Who's Online Avatars"),
        "desc" => "",
        "default" => array("checked", "checked")

) );

?>
```

There a more arrays but I shortened the code to save space. The question is: 
How can I include only the following code

```
 array(
            "type" => "section",
            "icon" => "acera-icon-preference",
            "title" => "General Settings",
            "id" => "general",
            "expanded" => "true"
        ),
```

in a conditional **if** somethink like this code (that get errors):

```
if(function_exists('bp_is_active') ): 

  array(
                "type" => "section",
                "icon" => "acera-icon-preference",
                "title" => "General Settings",
                "id" => "general",
                "expanded" => "true"
            ),

endif;
```

The function bp_is_active it check if BuddyPress plugin is instaled. I need that code to be displayed on my wp admin panel only if BuddyPress plugin is instaled.

Thanks!

Comment: do you try to create array if `if` condition is true ??

Comment: No, can you be more specific?

Comment: Are you saying that you create $options in any case, but want to add the array with "type" => "section" as first element only if the function bp_is_active exists? Right now your question is confusing.

Comment: The function bp_is_active it check if BuddyPress plugin is instaled. I need that code to be displayed on my wp admin panel only if BuddyPress plugin is instaled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `?:` ternary conditional operator:

```
$options = array(
  function_exists('bp_is_active') // condition
    ? array(...stuff...)          // if true
    : array(),                    // if false
  ...more arrays...
);
```

That will use an empty array if the condition is false. If you want nothing there (as opposed to `array()`), you'll need something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need semicolon `(;)`, following code is valid:

```
 if(function_exists('bp_is_active') ): 
     array(
            "type" => "section",
            "icon" => "acera-icon-preference",
            "title" => "General Settings",
            "id" => "general",
            "expanded" => "true"
          ); // <<--here

    endif;
```

or without `endif`:

```
     if(function_exists('bp_is_active') ){ 
     array(
            "type" => "section",
            "icon" => "acera-icon-preference",
            "title" => "General Settings",
            "id" => "general",
            "expanded" => "true"
          ); // <<--here
     }
```